# Get values from Gridview to textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, visual-studio-2012

How can I get data from a gridview to a textbox. I tried using:

```
TextBox3.Text = GridView1.Rows(1).cell(1).text;
```

but no luck.

[image]

Comment: winforms i assume

Comment: What is GridView? May be DataGridView? What component are you using?

Comment: 1) C# is case sensitive. 2) for the indexing of collection the `[ ]` parentheses are used

Comment: how did the values end up in the `GridView` ?

Comment: 1) Are rows and cells collections maybe 0-base indexed? 2) are you gridview and textboxes bound to any kind of a datasource? May be you should look at updating to / refreshing from underlaying datasource.

Comment: winform or aspnet or ??? . What control (namespace) are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
TextBox3.Text = GridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
```

Or

```
TextBox3.Text = GridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Text;
```

Comment: its giving an error saying "does not contain definition for value". Should I insert any using statements ?

Comment: Are you using asp.net? Then try with GridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Text

Comment: You use WPF, but not WinForms! Take me your XAML file!

Comment: This statement worked for me 
'TextBox3.Text = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text;'
thanks @TihomirTashev

Answer (score 0):

you where close. The Rows is an array, so u have to use brackets to get the index of an array

```
TextBox3.Text = GridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: its giving an error saying "does not contain definition for value". Am i missing any using statements ?

Comment: @VigneshSriram no you are not missing any using statements. You just forgot to add the necessary tag so that people know what technology you are using.